# How to identify a JSON object using swift and xctest framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestexpectation

Using `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(..)` we can create a JSON object. But is it possible to identify the object type ie. is it a JSON object or not.

I was just trying to check using Swift and XCTestFramework. I tried different ways but no solution still?

**Note:** After creation of JSON object, I can get the values and can also check the values. XCTest Framework is working fine to test those type of things. But, I stuck to identify the object type.

Anybody has any idea how to identify the JSON object programmatically using Swift and XCTest framework

`Update:` For example, for a website testing we can do the following:

```
if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse,
                responseURL = HTTPResponse.URL,
                MIMEType = HTTPResponse.MIMEType
{
  XCTAssertEqual(responseURL.absoluteString, URL.absoluteString, "HTTP response URL should be equal to original URL")
  XCTAssertEqual(HTTPResponse.statusCode, 200, "HTTP response status code should be 200")
  XCTAssertEqual(MIMEType, "text/html", "HTTP response content type should be text/html")
            } else {
                XCTFail("Response was not NSHTTPURLResponse")
            }
```

Is something possible like above for JSON?

Comment: if it's a "json object", then it's going to be a string `{...}`. so check the first/last characters...

Comment: json["key"] as? NSArray   ?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a valid string within your NSData parameter, but that String is not a valid JSON object, then the parser will throw an error. As from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:):

*If an error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object that describes the problem.*

So check if the object returned is actually an NSError. If you don't get an error, then I would safely assume that the object is indeed a valid JSON object.